# utf8 encoding on twitter api in node

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I am getting data from the twitter API in my node application. A typical response text is:

```
Hey, you can watch gameplays for example here &gt; http://t.co/J3gCsKcY81 or there &gt; http://t.co/VcRI2pArCd. Thanks!
```

But I cant seem to encode the information to utf-8. I have tried the 'utf8' module using the methods

```
utf8.decode(string);  utf8.encode(string)
```

Both return the same string that was given as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
&gt;
```

is no utf8 encoding its an html entity you can use the [node-html-entities](https://github.com/mdevils/node-html-entities) module:

```
entities.decode('&lt;&gt;&quot;&amp;&copy;&reg;'); // <>"&©®
```